# MUI tabs working but not animating changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I have a React app that displays a list of cards displaying assignment info for an educational app. Each card contains MUI tabs so that teachers can navigate through students' work. Simplified code below:

**teacherClass.jsx**

```
function TeacherClass(props) {

    const [classData, setClassData] = React.useState(props.classData);
    const [assignments, setAssignments] = React.useState([]);
    //assignments are found from Firebase elsewhere in this file. Omitted for simplicity.
    const [tabValue, setTabValue] = React.useState(0);

    const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
      setTabValue(newValue);
    }

    const AssignmentCard = (assignment) => ( 
        <Card>
            <Tabs value={tabValue} onChange={handleTabChange} >
                {classData.students ? classData.students.map((stu) => 
                    <Tab label={stu.name} value={stu} />) : null }
            </Tabs>
        </Card>
    ) 

    return ( 
        <div>
            { assignments ? assignments.map((assignment) => AssignmentCard(assignment)) : null }
        </div>
    );
}

export default TeacherClass;
```

This works just fine, however the problem is that when I change tabs, it changes the tab for EVERY card, not just the one that I selected. I thought I could fix this by having my tabValue useState as an array or something, but instead decided to create a new component so that each card could have its own useState:

**teacherAssignmentCard.jsx**

```
function TeacherAssignmentCard(props) {

    const classData = props.classData;
    const assignment = props.assignmentData;
    const [tabValue, setTabValue] = React.useState(classData.students[0]);

const AssignmentCard = () => {Same code as 'AssignmentCard' in 'teacherClass.jsx',
but with no argument as 'assignment' comes from props}

return (
    <AssignmentCard />
);
```

and in **teacherClass.jsx** I of course changed the return:

```
return ( 
    <div>
        { assignments ? assignments.map((assignment) => 
        <TeacherAssignmentCard classData={classData} assignmentData={assignment} />) : null}
    </div>
);
```

I thought this was a fairly elegant solution and it worked perfectly. Each tab click only changes the tab for one assignment. *However*, what was very strange was that I lost the nice smooth MUI animation where the line underneath the tab slides over to the new tab. Instead it just repositions instantly.

I have checked and rewritten my code a half dozen times and made sure it's exactly the same. Any ideas what could be causing this weird behaviour or how to fix it?? Thank you.

Comment: If you inspect the html, there should be a span element as a child of the tabs that is the "indicator" that animates. Specifically the "transition" prop is what gives the indicator the animation. I assume the transition prop is still there, if it's no longer animating though it feels like maybe the entire tabs component is being added/removed to the DOM instead of just being updated. If the entire component is being added/removed from the tree, you'd see the tab "update" but not animate because the transition prop wouldn't have seen the absolute position change (since it was a new render).

Comment: In the `teacherClass.jsx` file, does adding a unique `key` prop to the <TeacherAssignmentCard> resolve the issues? The 'key' prop should be used when using `.map` function as React uses it to determine rerenders.